# Alexa custom OAuth 2.0 server, https certificate

Tags: oauth-2.0, ssl-certificate, alexa-skills-kit

We implement a custom OAuth2.0 server for Alexa smart home service, and find some issues.

It works under following conditions.

1. The certificate **MUST** be signed by trusted organization.
2. The https port **MUST** be `443`, not a custom port. (Ex: 60123)

`But now, the above issues are trouble.`

Because the published mobile apps, they depend on the server with `self-signed` certificate. If replacing with trusted certificate, app will fail to communicate with server. Some app are co-worked with another company, they have no plan, and no will to update app recently.

Eventually we will meet the above 2 conditions, but not now.

So, for mobile apps, we restore the certificate with `self-signed` on the server. But we hope the account linking of alexa skill (OAuth 2.0) could work too.

### My Question:

So, for `alexa service`, how to let oauth2 work with self-signed certificate? 
Or, let oauth2 work with a trusted signed certificate, but with a custom port (Ex: 12345)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You did not ask a question actually.

Comment: @zerkms, thanks, I update my question.

Comment: Amazon requires both - amazon trusted CA signed certificate and port 443. https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service#requirements-for-your-web-service

Comment: @zerkms, Thank you very much.